# How do I send a command after submitting a form?

Tags: forms

I need to do something when the user submits a form so that it sends a command to the server, :

```
 if($_GET["cmd"]=="save")
```

Got to do something with the thing above,
I thought of using:

```
<a href="?cmd=save">Save</a>
```

But if I do that it will not complete the form action so:

```
<form action="{{ pageName }}">
```

Will not be executed...
So how would I fix this problem?
thanks all :)

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal way to do this is to use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9.0.x) to add a submit hook, and then add your command in the submit hook.  Here's a simple example.

You'll need to add this code to [a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules).

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'my_form_id') {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_my_form_submit';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_my_form_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  // Insert command here.
}
```